# How can you tell if you've been a victim of the recent sms bug?

Tags: sms

How would one know if their phone was or is afflicted by the recent bug (sending sms to the wrong people)?

Comment: Title is unclear: HTC's implementation of Android SMS handling in the past has been buggy in the extreme - so maybe pick a better title?

Comment: It's a well known and specific bug that affects all phones running the android os. Anyone that regularly follows android news should be familiar.  If you search google for "android sms bug" pretty much every result is about it. When I'm at a computer and not posting from my phone I'll add more info.

Comment: Apparently Google now believe that there were two separate SMS bugs that they've managed to reproduce, and now have fixes for. More here http://www.androidguys.com/2011/01/06/google-working-fixes-sms-bugs/ no word yet on when or how the fixes will be distributed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this post](http://www.androidguys.com/2011/01/03/android-sms-bug-real/), it seems that only very specific conditions seem to trigger this bug. Also, AFAIK, this only seems to affect the default Messaging app, using a replacement like Handcent seems to be the way to go. More info on the bug [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1233).

> Specifically, there is something about
>   certain email-to-SMS messages that
>   corrupts Android's SQLite database,
>   causing unpredictable results
>   thereafter. The most commonly cited
>   offender is alerts sent by Bank of
>   America, though SMS alerts sent by
>   LinkedIn and T-Mobile are also cited.
>   It's possible that any SMS where the
>   sender is an email address will do the
>   trick, or it's possible there's
>   something else these specific senders'
>   messages have in common.
>
> To be clear: if you've never received
>   one of these corrupting messages, you
>   will never be able to reproduce the
>   bug. That's why it's only affecting a
>   small group of Android users.
>
> If you have fallen prey to the issue,
>   you should be able to fix it by
>   performing a hard reset (wiping all
>   data) and then blocking the offending
>   sender(s) from sending you texts in
>   the future.

Comment: The bug report you linked to mentions that the mis-directed SMSs are sent to the first contact in your contact list, so is it worth adding a new contact to the beginning of your list ('Mr Aaaa Aaaa') with your own number?

Comment: I've had a contact like that for years, ever since my friend 'Adam' kept complaining that my phone kept ringing him from my pocket when I forgot to lock it.

Comment: Might be a good idea.